# How to pick an element from dd list?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to pick every role of every user from database.I have table `career_solutions`, with column `user_id`, and table `role_users` with columns `id`,`user_id` and `role_user`.I tried this code :

```
$role = User::with('role')
->where ('id', $id)
->first();
dd($role->role);
```

And this returns me this list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHjgf.jpg

How can I pick the id of role from that list? I tried also `dd($role->role->id);`, but this returns me `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id`.

Comment: Have you checked `$role->role[0]->id`?

Comment: Your database structure says that a user can have multiple roles. That is why you are getting a collection or roles under `$role->role` if you can only have 1 role per user then you might be better of adding the `role_id` in the users table. If you can have multiple roles per user then your question does not seem to reflect this

Comment: Thank you Rahul! That's saved my task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the first role in the collection via 0 index and read the desired property

```php
$roles = User::with('role')
->where ('id', $id)
->first();

dd($roles->role[0]->id);
```

Comment: Hi man :) Can I make a relation between user_id from career_solutions table and role_id from role_users table?